# Executing a function after each-loop has completed

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout, each, program-flow

Hey there,
I'm working on a jQuery each()-loop containing an ajax-request an a setTimeout. That's giving me some issues with the program flow.

```
xml_queries: function (data) {
    var values = [];

    // ...

    $.each(data, function(index, value) {

        // ...

        // Start xml query
        var i = 0;
        get_data(value.value);

        function get_data(value) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/admin/scanner/get_music_data/' + value,
                dataTaype: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    if ( response === 'FALSE' ) {
                        // Start recursion - up to 3 Retries
                        if ( ++i <= 3 ) {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                get_data();
                            }, 100);
                        } else {
                            // ...
                        }
                    } else {
                        values.push(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    // return values;
    console.log(values);
}
```

My problem is that the console.log() in the last line is fired immediatly (while the loop is still processing data). Isn't there any easy possibility to wait for the loop to finish? \:

Best regards!

Comment: It's the usual Ajax-is-asynchronous problem. There are a **ton** of questions on SO about this in one flavor or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current code, the most straightforward way would be to set $.ajax's `async` option to false, to force a synchronous request, causing JavaScript to wait for it to complete before continuing to execute the subsequent statements (it won't do this for *asynchronous* requests).

```
$.ajax(
   {
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    ...
```

That will block your browser for the duration of each request (yuck). Another way to do it would be to redesign your application such that the next ajax call is called from within the success callback of the first, e.g.:

```
$.ajax(
   {
    type: 'POST',
    ...
    success: function() {
        doAjaxThingie();
    }
```

Comment: Better yet would be to explain the asynchronous behavior - but I am bleedin' _sick_ of these questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it quite simple. On my attempts searching for a solution I read that setTimeout would cause that issue.
Btw: Is the synchrone processing done by multiple threads?

Comment: @Matt - fair enough. I've answered this at least six or seven times. One of the reasons it is coming up repeatedly, I think, is because the phrasing of such question is very inconsistent, they seem to be difficult to find by googling. Perhaps we should set a policy on SO whereby they get the additional tag 'asynchrony' :)

Comment: I fully agree - given the number of times this has come up, it might warrant a bit of discussion on meta.